# Cannot scroll to specific view in scrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a couple of `EditText`s in a ScrollView. Below one `EditText` there's a `TextView`. When soft keyboard focus on that `EditText` I want to scroll to the `TextView` I mentioned above so I'm sure it's also visible (it contains some info for the `EditText` ).

So I have added a focus listener to that `EditText` and inside there I have this code :

```
        svContainer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                svContainer.smoothScrollTo(0 , tvInfo.getBottom());


            }
        }, 300);
```

but nothing happens. `TextView` stays hidden below keyboard.
Logcat gives me for `tvInfo.getBottom() == 717`

EDIT : While if I change the `smoothScrollTo()` with `svContainer.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` then its scrolling all the way to the bottom !

EDIT 2 : adds xml code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
android:id="@+id/sv_container"
android:fillViewport="false" android:background="@color/getstarted_blue_bg"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_about_you_container"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/get_started_about_you" android:textColor="@color/white" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_industry"
        android:maxLines="1" android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/et_profession"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large" android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_profession"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/et_company"
        android:maxLines="1" android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large" android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_company"
        android:hint="@string/get_started_company" android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:maxLines="1" android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large" android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_anchor" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="AnchorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
svContainer.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                svContainer.scrollTo(0, tvInfo.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
```

ANd use :
in activity tag in manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: I have tried this before too, but still there's no scrolling

Comment: Nope `stateHidden` did not help

Comment: Try to change fillviewport=true in scrollview